# How to use case statment in where condition(sql)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I try to write a query with sql that get one parameter and use this parameter in where section of below query  but get error: 
I want do this :

if `@state` equal with 2 Check in `where` condition `@state=2`

if `@state` equal with 3 Check in `where` condition `@state=3`

if `@state` equal with 0 then  don't Check in `where` condition

I try to write this statement with case but get syntax error

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl1
WHERE  @StartDate <= Cast([date] AS DATE)
       AND Cast([date] AS DATE) <= @endDate
       AND [reservetype] = @Type
       AND  CASE
                       WHEN @State = 2 THEN [state]=2
                       WHEN @State = 3 THEN [state]=3
                       WHEN @State = 0 then ....
                     END
```

Comment: Based on the syntax, I added the SQL Server tag.

Comment: Are you trying to assign a value to [state] in the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `case` for this, then the logic is:

```
[state] = (CASE WHEN @State IN (2, 3) THEN @state
                ELSE [state]
           END)
```

This does what you want, assuming that `state` is not `NULL`.

Note:

I would write the conditions as:

```
WHERE [date] >= @StartDate AND
      [date] < DATEADD(day, 1, @endDate) AND
      [reservetype] = @Type AND
      ((@state IN (2, 3) and [state] = @state) OR
       (@state NOT IN (2, 3))
      )
```

I changed the date arithmetic to remove the `cast()`.  Although SQL Server can use an index when casting a date/time to `date`, it might get confused with a complicated `WHERE` clause.  So, this version might optimize better depending on the indexes.

Comment: how can I add condition into where statement such as my code?

Comment: The OP didn't mention any comparisons of either `state` to `1`.

Comment: @underscore_d . . . The OP did before the edits.  You can click on the blue "edited . . . " line to see previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken you want this trivial logic:

```
...
WHERE (@State = 0 or t.State = @State)
   AND ...
```